# Active non-link navbar item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a standard bootstrap navbar that looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href='#'>Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Current section of the web site is marked as `active` class and it works fine. Now I want the navbar item `Item 1` not to be a link when current page is the one `Item 1` links to (because a link that points to current page has no point), but I still want it to be highlighted as active page. Issue is, as soon as a remove `a` element from a `li` highlight drops.

I tried simply dropping the anchor tag:

```
            <li class="active">Item 1</li>
```

putting `p.navbar-text` around the item:

```
            <li class="active"><p class='navbar-text'>Item 1</p></li>
```

And few other things, none worked so far.

I understand that I could do something like:

```
            <li class="active"><p class='navbar-text' style='background-color: #e7e7e7; padding: 15px; margin: 0'>Item 1</p></li>
```

to get what I want. Also, this seem to work:

```
            <li class="active"><a>Item 1</a></li>
```

but it's semantically wrong.

Is it possible to achieve without adding my own CSS for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the [less files for the navbar](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/less/navbar.less#L395) only apply this styling to anchor elements. You could copy over this styling to apply to things like `span` or `p` for your use, but there's no way with the default bootstrap css to get this to apply otherwise.